# How to display a command's output without flooding the PowerShell Console?

Tags: powershell

I'm running a silent SQL installer from a .ps1 install script. The SQL installer is set to /Quiet and /DisplayProgress. I had recently sent it to a new console window to show output but not flood the console, but recently I've made the switch where I remote in via `Enter-PSSession`, so I wouldn't see the new window.

Is there a way I can use `Write-Progress` or something else to display like 6 scrolling lines at a time?

Comment: Can you be more specific with how it's 'flooding' the console, and with what exactly you're hoping to have it display instead?

Comment: The installer generates hundreds of lines of output. I'd like the user to be able to see that, but I don't want so much that it floods the output. I was thinking of a scrolling pane of 5-10 lines. I'm thinking `Write-Progress`, because it only displays when the command is running and disappears afterwards - it doesn't flood the display.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
function Write-SomeContent {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Object[]] $Content
    )

    Clear-Host;
    $pos = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates;
    $pos.X = 0;
    $pos.Y = 0;
    $Host.ui.RawUI.CursorPosition = $pos;

    foreach ($Object in $Content) {
        Write-Host -Object $Object;
    }
}

Write-SomeContent 'Message 1', 'Message 2', 'Message 3', 'Message 4', 'Message 5', 'Message 6';
```

Just keep making calls to Write-SomeContent, and it will only occupy as many lines as objects you pass into it.

Comment: This clears everything, which isn't really what I want. I want the old stuff to still display, but just display a snapshot of what's happening.